# Trying to expand treegrid with fields not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

First of all, I'm super new to LWC. This is really my first project. I am trying to build a treegrid on the Application__c object and have a display of all related App_Equipment__c records (relationship field is Application__c) and have them sorted by Type__c which expands to sort by Model_Number__c. Can someone help me figure this out?

This is what it looks like right now:
[image: current state]

My code is:

```
public with sharing class AppEquipmentController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<Application__c> getNewEquipForApps(){
        return [SELECT Name, (
                SELECT Id, Model_Number__c, Type__c FROM App_Equipment__r ORDER BY Type__c, Model_Number__c)
                FROM Application__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Application__c FROM App_Equipment__c)];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
   <template>
        <lightning-tree-grid
          columns={columns}
          data={myData}
          key-field="Id"
          onrowaction={handleRowAction}
        >
        </lightning-tree-grid>
      </template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

import getNewEquipForApps from "@salesforce/apex/AppEquipmentController.getNewEquipForApps";

const actions = [{ label: "Edit", name: "edit_record" }];

const COLS = [
    {
        fieldName: "Type__c",
        label: "Type",
    },
    {
        fieldName: "Model_Number__c",
        label: "Model Number",

    },
    {
        type: "action",
        label: "Edit Record",
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
            menuAlignment: "right",
        },
    },
];

export default class MyTreeGrid extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track myData = [];
    columns = COLS;
    error;

    @wire(getNewEquipForApps)
    wiredEquipment({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            // Handle error
            this.error = error;
        } else if (data) {
            // Process record data
            var strData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            strData.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.Type__c < b.Type__c) return -1;
                if (a.Type__c > b.Type__c) return 1;
                //If Type__c is the same, sort by Model_Number__c
                if (a.Model_Number__c > b.Model_Number__c) return -1;
                if (a.Model_Number__c < b.Model_Number__c) return 1;
            })

            strData.map((row, index) => {
                if (row["App_Equipment__r"]) {
                    row._children = row["App_Equipment__r"]; //define rows with children
                    delete row.Equipment;

                    let iconKey = "iconName";
                    row[iconKey] = "standard:lightning_contact";
                }
            });
            this.myData = strData;
        }
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const action = event.detail.action;
        const row = event.detail.row;
        switch (action.name) {
            case "edit_record":
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: "standard__objectPage",
                    attributes: {
                        objectApiName: "App_Equipment__c",
                        actionName: "edit",
                        recordId: row.Id,
                    },
                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

jsmeta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```